# Loading ApplicationContext Fails Spring java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I am developing a Spring application and in the very beginning I am facing an issue, I get the following error

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext`
when try to load the `ApplicationContext`

This is the `App.java` file which is supposed to start the Application

public class App {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/web/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml");


    }
 }
```

This is the context of `applicationContext.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />

</beans>
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:612)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:683)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1445)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:445)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:415)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:101)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
at com.nudicode.Poker.App.main(App.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

can anyone help me please through it and also please let me know if I have to provide more code from other part of the application.

Comment: If you just started, delete everything, and go for Spring Boot: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may miss `servlet-api.jar` in your build path;) Here is the [jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api).

Comment: Any idea why is it required?? i just tried running a main method using spring framework!! And it worked for me too!!